# Evaluate by Contour Integration

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I am able to solve this problem by Cauchy Residue theorem, but not by contour integration. (i.e Taking integration in semicircle of radius R and x-axis from -R to +R).
$$
I = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{1-2a\cos(t)+a^2}dt\,.
$$

$$ Given : a^2 < 1 $$

PS: Not a homework question, but practice question

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The contour is a circle here.

Comment: Choosing $z$ correctly $\cos(t) = \frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}$

Comment: @zokomoko Finding the given integral using contour integration.

Comment: @FDP I got your point. Thanks!

Comment: Then what is your solution ?